# Modifying diagonals in multidimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, diagonal

I have a multidimensional numpy array of shape (7, 3, 7, 3) and I would like to modify the generalized diagonal in which axis 0 and axis 2 coincide. This generalized diagonal would be defined as those elements of the array whose 0th and 2nd index coincide, and would have shape (3, 3, 7).

Doing:

```
arr.diagonal(axis1=0, axis2=2)
```

I can access to the elements of the diagonal, but I cannot modify them 'in place', at least in version 1.8.2 of numpy.

[Numpy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) explains that with version 1.10 this might be possible. However, since I depend on other people using the same code, updating to numpy 1.10 is not an option. Documentation also suggests using .copy() in order to have a portable solution, but .copy() will make a copy of the array, but this is of no help if I want to modify the diagonals of the original array.

Alternatively, I have tried indexing the diagonal elements directly [with input taken from numpy.indices((7, 3, 7, 3))], but with no success.

How could I access the elements of the generalized diagonal to modify the original array in numpy 1.8.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to create such a generalized diagonal view is to use the `as_strided` function from the module `numpy.lib.stride_tricks`.  The stride for the axis associated with the diagonal of the two axes is the sum of the strides of those axes.

For example:

```
In [196]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
```

Create an array with shape (7, 3, 7, 3):

```
In [197]: a = np.arange(21*21).reshape(7,3,7,3)

In [198]: a[5, :, 5, :]
Out[198]: 
array([[330, 331, 332],
       [351, 352, 353],
       [372, 373, 374]])
```

Create a view of the "diagonal" associated with axes 0 and 2.  The view has shape (3, 3, 7):

```
In [199]: d = as_strided(a, strides=(a.strides[1], a.strides[3], a.strides[0] + a.strides[2]), shape=(3, 3, 7))
```

Check that, for example, `d[:, :, 5]` is the same as `a[5, :, 5, :]`:

```
In [200]: d[:, :, 5]
Out[200]: 
array([[330, 331, 332],
       [351, 352, 353],
       [372, 373, 374]])
```

Verify that `d` is a view of `a` by modifying `d` and seeing that `a` has changed:

```
In [201]: d[1, 1, 5] = -1

In [202]: a[5, :, 5, :]
Out[202]: 
array([[330, 331, 332],
       [351,  -1, 353],
       [372, 373, 374]])
```

Be careful with `as_strided`!  If you get the arguments wrong, you can write to memory outside of `a`, possibly causing python to crash.